# What is main reason to use generics TypeScript in case?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

There is a default example how to use generic types in TypeScript:

```
class Greeter<T> {
    greeting: T;
    constructor(message: T) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter<string>("Hello, world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

What is main reason to use this? Why I can not use just `:any` type in this example instead `T`?

Comment: You can use `: any` anywhere, but you lose the benefits of specifying a type, as usual.

Comment: What it gives me, if I just write message in alert window? I know I can pass number, but what is difference?

Comment: Can you share a real sample?

Comment: Isn't it nice to be able to have an Array<Person>, and have the compiler prevent you from storing anything other than persons in the array, and infer automatically, with code completion in the IDE, that any element from that array is a Person? That's a realistic example, that shows why generics are useful.

Comment: Why I must store another information in array Person if it contains information only about Person? It is logical too.

Comment: `any` is the type of all values that TypeScript will not provide tooling for. You only get the benefits of the language when the types of values are not `any`. Also note that don't need to specify the type argument when calling a generic function and generally should not. `new Greeter("Hello, world")` infers `Greeter<string>`.

Comment: I can create custom model Person and extend this any time adding properties or extending by another model it is not?

Comment: Why not to create local array and iterate model `Person` to `PersonArray`?

Comment: I can not feel real case when it is required

Comment: -1 There are hundreds of articles that talk about how/why to use generics.  For example, [Wikipedia - Generic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).  This question not only does not add value to SO, it's most likely off-topic.

Comment: @Karabah you want to reimplement array every time you need to store a new type of value in any array?

Comment: For advanced examples of how to use TS generics you can look at this excellent article at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-generics-in-typescript).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main reason to use generics in TypeScript (and any other programming language) is to enable types (classes, types, or interfaces) to act as parameters. It helps us reuse the same code for different types of input since the type itself is available as a parameter.

Some benefits of generics are:

- Defining a relationship between input and output parameters types. For example, `function test <T>(input: T[]): T { ... }` allows you to make sure input and output use the same type, though input as an array.
- Stronger type checks at compile time will be available. In the case of above example, compiler lets you know array methods are available for `input` and not any other methods.
- You can remove some unnecessary type casts. For example, when you have `const list: Array<Item> = []`, going over array elements, you will have access to all the `Item` members.
- Using generics, you can define more generalized algorithms. For example, assume you have a base class called `Account` containing some methods and properties. Later, several other classes (`Checking`, `Saving`, and `MoneyMarket`) extend this class. You can have a function that performs some operations on any of the extended classes such as `function getBalance <T extends Account>(account: T): number { ... }`.

Comment: The last one benefit doesn't make sense to me. What's the advantage between `getBalance(account: Account): number` and your use of that generic? Without generics you are also able to use any of the child classes.

Comment: @IvánPérez However with generics it is guaranteed that everywhere the type `T` is used in the function/class, it is always the *same* specific type declared in the generic (e.g. `Checking`), not *any* of types inheriting from `Animal`.

Comment: @user14967413 I think that it just makes sense if you use `T` more than once in the function signature (e.g. in another parameter or in the return type). Otherwise, that `T` cannot be narrowed down to any inheriting type, so it's the same as using the base class.

Comment: @IvánPérez Right. Moreover,`T` could be used not only in function signature, but also in local function variable declarations.